# IE iFrame loading icon

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

Good day,
I have a problem with IE and iframes.
So I have a huge application with legacy code, designed in early 2000. iFrames are used everywhere.
When something big is loaded inside the iframe, there is no display in browser throbber. So the loading icon starts spinning only when the main page is loaded, not iframes, so its impossible to say if anything is happening at all.

The users complain, that IE10+ gives them this problem, earlier versions worked. For me IE9 also has this issue.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to use JS on every page and manually add the 'loading please wait' icon or message, there are more than 100 pages with more then one iframe on each.

Chrome works fine, but nothing except IE can be used.

Could you please recommend solution for this trouble?